# expected 'char**' but argument is of type 'char***'

Tags: c

```
void printboard (char **board, int n)
```

In my main function I created the two dimensional array using

```
char **board;
board = malloc(dim);
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    board[i] = malloc(dim);
}
```

After I entered characters into my array, I used

```
printBoard(&board, dim);
```

and while compiling, I get the error

```
note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char***'
```

Comment: `char **board` is a pointer to a pointer, then you get a pointer to it again by saying: `&board`, which returns a pointer to `board`.

Answer (score 3):

Your first malloc is no good. You want to allocate space for `dim` pointers of type `char*`. So you need:

```
board = malloc(dim*sizeof(char*));
```

And then the compilation error. That's because `&board` is the address of `board`. Since `board` has type `char**`, then `&board` has type `char***`. Which is what the compiler said. You need to pass `board` rather than `&board`.

```
printBoard(board, dim);
```

Answer (score 0):

`&varname` gives you a pointer to that variable. `&board`, where board is an `int**`, gives you a pointer to an `int**`; in other words, and `int***`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your board space to be of type char, but what happens when your needs change?  You should probably provide a struct or typedef, then changes are a little easier to make, should your needs/requirements change.

```
typedef char boardspace;
```

You could just allocate a single array, of dimension rowsize x columsize, and then use a forumla to find the board position by calculating position = row*columsize+column,

```
boardspace* BoardNew(int dim)
{
    int i;
    if (dim<4) dim=4;
    //allocate as single array, dim x dim
    boardspace* newboard = malloc(sizeof(boardspace)*dim*dim);
    return newboard;
}
void BoardPrint (boardspace* board, int dimension);
```

Using this approach, you would convert a location pair (row,column) into an array location using a formula/function,

```
int boardposition(int dim, int row, int col)
{
    return row*dim + col;
}
```

Or, you can allocate an array of rows, each containing a pointer to the array of columns.  But that means you need to check the result of multiple mallocs, and the error handling becomes more difficult,

```
//or,
boardspace** BoardNew(int dim)
{
    int i;
    int error=0;
    //allocate as array of rows of pointers to columns
    boardspace** rows = malloc(sizeof(boardspace*)*dim);
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        if( !( rows[i] = malloc(sizeof(boardspace))) ) error++;
    }
    if( error ) {
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            free(rows[i]);
        }
        free(rows);
    }
    return rows;
}
void BoardPrint (boardspace** board, int dimension);
```

The above choices drive everything else.

You could recognize that you may need more than just a single character for board location (perhaps a content list, and lots of other stuff).  Here you have the same choices for one-dimension vs. two-dimension board allocation, but you also have a board containment structure, which can store both the board, and the dimensions.

```
typedef struct space_s
{
    char space;
} SpaceObj;
typedef struct board_s
{
    int dim;
    SpaceObj* board;
} BoardObj;
```

Allocate a board in one dimension, using the aforementioned board position formula,

```
BoardObj* BoardNew(int dim)
{
    if (dim<4) dim=4;
    BoardObj* bp = malloc(sizeof(BoardObj));
    if(!bp) return NULL;
    bp->dim = dim;
    SpaceObj* sp = malloc(sizeof(SpaceObj)*dim*dim);
    if(!bp) { free(bp); return NULL; }
    return sp;
}
void BoardPrint (BoardObj* board);
```

Note that by storing dimension in the board structure, you do not have to carry that value around,

```
int boardposition(BoardObj* board, int row, int col)
{
    return row*(board->dim) + col;
}
```

Or you can use the two-dimension approach, but for the board structure,

```
//or,
typedef struct board_s
{
    int dim;
    SpaceObj** rows;
} BoardObj;
BoardObj* BoardNew(int dim)
{
    int i;
    int error=0;
    if (dim<4) dim=4;
    BoardObj* bp = malloc(sizeof(BoardObj));
    if(!bp) return NULL;
    bp->dim = dim;
    SpaceObj** rows;
    if( !(rows = malloc(sizeof(SpaceObj*)*dim)) ) { free(bp); return NULL; }
    bp->rows = rows;
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        bp->rows[i] = rows[i] = malloc(dim);
    }
    if(error) {
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            free(rows[i]);
        }
        free(rows);
        free(bp);
    }
    return bp;
}
void BoardPrint (BoardObj* board);
```

And you need to allocate, and pass around your board in different ways, here they are illustrated,

```
main()
{
    int dim = 8;
    //and then you have one of these to manipulate,
    boardspace* board = BoardNew(dim);
    boardspace** board = BoardNew(dim);
    BoardObj* board = BoardNew(dim);
    BoardObj* board = BoardNew(dim);

    //which can be addressed in the appropriate way,
    BoardPrint(board, dim);
    BoardPrint(board, dim);
    BoardPrint(board);
    BoardPrint(board);

}
```